# MongoEngine delete document

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following MongoEngine document

```
{
    '_id': 'some_id',
    'data': 'some_data'
}
```

How can I `delete` this document using MongoEngine?

**What I've tried:**

```
import my_collection

obj = my_collection.MyCol.objects.get(_id='some_id')
# obj is correctly found - let's continue

obj.delete()
# mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: 'None' is not a valid ObjectId

obj.delete('some_id')
# TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

obj.delete(_id='some_id')
# mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: 'None' is not a valid ObjectId
```

-- *note*

Oddly enough, the following works perfectly:

```
my_collection.MyCol.objects.delete()
# delete all documents in the collection
```

But I've followed [MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/) docs, and still can't manage to delete just **one specific document**.

Comment: I think [that note](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html#deleting-documents) has something to do with that: `Note that this will only work if the document exists in the database and has a valid id.`

Comment: @alecxe mmm I thought about this actually, but dismissed it because MongoEngine says `'None' is not a valid ObjectId` - not `'some_id'`

Comment: Posted a current theory as an answer. Do you have a custom primary key/field defined on the model? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce adding `primary_key=True` in the `_id` field definition solved the problem - thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your document overrides `_id`, you must indicate that it's still the primary key. Change your document class definition from:

```
class MyCol(Document):
    _id = db.StringField()
    ...
```

To specify the primary key:

```
class MyCol(Document):
    _id = db.StringField(primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score 6):

When referencing mongoengine ObjecIds you don't use the underscore.

```
obj = my_collection.MyCol.objects.get(id='some_id')
```

or

```
obj = my_collection.MyCol.objects(id='some_id')
obj.delete()
```

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand and according to the [note in the docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html#deleting-documents):

> Note that this will only work if the document exists in the database and has a valid id

`obj.delete()` would only work if the object ID - the `obj.id` property - has a valid `ObjectId` value. In your case, you don't have `obj.id` defined, use the `objects.delete()` syntax:

```
my_collection.MyCol.objects.delete()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete one specific document using the following command

```
my_collection.MyCol.objects(id='some_id').delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

my_collection.MyCol.objects(id='some_id').delete()

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to mark the document id as the primary key.

```
from bson import ObjectId
from conn import db
class ProductModel(db.Document):
    meta = {'collection': 'products'}
    _id = db.ObjectIdField() #throws the exception
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(primary_key=True,default=ObjectId) #correct way to not throw exception

    @classmethod
    def getById(cls, idProduct: str):
        return cls.objects(_id=ObjectId(idProduto)).first()
```

#### How to use

```
#from bson import ObjectId

id = 630a18fb70392af65e9d63bc
if ObjectId.is_valid(id) == False:
    return {'message':'Provide a valid id.'}

ProductModel.getById(idProduct=id).delete()
```